# Montar un lamda stream

Tags: java-8

Estoy intentado montado una lambda pero no soy capaz. Os dejo lo que he realizado.

```
List<ProveedorDTO> listaDTO = servicio.buscaquedaXIdCliente(id)
                .forEach(proveedor -> mapper.mapeoADTO(proveedor));
```

- `servicio.buscaquedaXIdCliente(id)` da una lista de proveedores
- `mapper.mapeoADTO` mapea un proveedor y lo convierte en un DTO

La idea es sacar la lista de DTO con un lambda o un stream.

Answer (score 0):

El método `forEach` no devuelve nada, es para crear "side effects". Lo que necesitas es usar el método `map` de la interfaz Stream:

```
List<ProveedorDTO> listaDTO = servicio.buscaquedaXIdCliente(id).stream()
        .map(mapper::mapeoADTO)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: el toList no le mola, dice que no ese metodo no esta definido

Comment: Es la costumbre de usar `import` estáticos... es de la clase Collectors. Editado para ponerlo explícitamente